# Session management and inmemory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am able to write a program uisng expressjs.
I have written the username and password ina  json file and accessing when I get a request.

```
req.body.password == users[req.body.username].password)
```

I want to copy the sessionID (SID) created and send to the client.
once I get a new request I want to check if it is there in local(inmemmory) if it is not there I want to send a different Error code to the user.

```
if(req.session.id=
```

My question is when not using redis (or) any DB, how can I store these session ID inmemory ? I  understand if it is inmemory on Restart all the data is gone.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a session store, Express (Connect) defaults to memory session store.

Comment: thank  you for the reply. how to store session.id? can you give me more onfo